# Boost named_condition implementation

Tags: c++, linux, boost

What is native Linux API used for Boost named_condition class implementation? In Windows, I guess, this is CreateEvent, I want to know what Linux feature can be used to get this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posix Threads Condition Variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal)

Comment: I ask about named condition variables, which are used for interprocess communication.

Comment: Pthreads condition variables can be used for interprocess communication, see pthread_condattr_setpshared(P). That's apparently what Boost uses.